# How to apply compositing after stopped rendering?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

It's often the case that it's not known how many samples are needed to render a picture. So I usually set a higher value and when the result already suits me I stop rendering. But if you applied compositing to picture, it doesn't apply when you stop rendering. So how do so that compositing apply when I want to stop rendering before it reached max samples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What advantages in using progressive rendering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/what-advantages-in-using-progressive-rendering)

Comment: Save the render as an image file then do the compositing from the external file from another scene.

Comment: Changing any value of any node in the compositing node tree will invoke processing of the compositing tree. Note though that if there aren't enough resources after rendering (e.g. not enough RAM available for compositing to be finished) Blender will crash with render. So better save it to OpenEXR file and then start experimenting

Answer (score 1):

You can save the result of progressive rendering as an image file (exr for maximum information) then do the compositing in an external .blend-file.
See also: [What advantages in using progressive rendering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/what-advantages-in-using-progressive-rendering/51896#51896)